# Godot 'apksigner' returned with error #126

Tags: sdk, godot

I'm getting this error 'apksigner' returned with error while exporting apk in godot. How can i fix it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what I have been able to find, the return code 126 means a command is not executable. Which I believe refers to permissions. Thus, make sure you have permission to execute Java.

Java should be should in Path (Environment variable), the location must be where you have the JDK installed.

*By the way, apksigner is not in the JDK. Instead it is the "build-tools" folder inside the SDK path (configured in Editor Settings -> Export -> Android -> Android SDK Path).*